# Frequently getting - There was a problem connecting to your instance (Not first time setup)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2

I'm frequently receiving the error **There was a problem connecting to your instance** when connecting via AWS console. I have a database instance running there and the application connecting to this server for DB service goes down!

This is neither a new instance having a network config error nor this has been purposefully isolated. Considering a day, I am able to connect to this instance for about 10hours, and for the rest, I get this error! So this is definitely not a configuration error.
Any advice/suggestion to debug this further for a permanent fix please? TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here so that might help someone some day! This is not a solution to the question that I asked, but a work around. I cloned the existing instance to a new instance and monitored both for couple of days. Turns out the new instance worked perfectly while the old one still had the issue.
Probably something with the instance itself.

While am not certainly sure, the AWS mainly comprises of FPGA and there might be some interim issue within it!

Finally terminated the old one! Not a solution, but this work-around works!

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue multiple times, each time AWS recommends to either upgrade the plan for support and if not, aws recommends to create a new instance, move the contents here and terminate the old one! So I'm actively looking for a solution aswell.

PS: Posting here as answer since I don't have reputation to make comments.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Absolutely, I've seen similar response from them!